# How do I get my app to use my new API keys?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I had a typo in my .gitignore file so I accidentally pushed my Stripe API keys to github.    So I got new keys and added them to my project (deleted the old keys) but I am now getting this error...

```
(node:16540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expired API Key provided: sk_test_********************Dd4e
```

**My code below**
Controller

```
charge(req, res, next){
    let amount = 1500;
    const keySecret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
    const stripe = require("stripe")(keySecret);

    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })
    .then(customer =>
        stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: "Sample Charge",
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.id
    }));
}
```

How do I prevent my app from using my old keys and use my new keys I added to the .env file?

Comment: Hi @Ryan, might be silly request. Have you tried to restart your process to make the `.env` effective?

Comment: @wsw I did restart the app and have the same issue.  Is that what you mean by restarting `process`?

Comment: yes @Ryan, that's what I meant. in that case, another guess: did you pass the key in the form of command line environment parameters. such as `SECRET_KEY=sk_xxxx node app.js`? I am not sure which will take precedence when `.env` and `environment parameters` are both there

Comment: It's working now.  I'm really not sure why though because I hadn't changed anything.  Thanks for the help though!